# Is it possible to a molecule go through spaces between a solid material without breaking it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, material-science

Imagine the following system:

We have a 3-dimensional box that is completely closed and have no connection to the environment outside of it. The walls of this box are made by some material $R$. Inside of that box, we only have a bunch of molecules of some random element $A$.

Assume that the state of $R$ is solid and $A$ is Gas.

If we increase the temperature of the molecules of the element $A$, we're going to increase the pressure on the walls, and probably with some high temperature, we are going to break the material $R$.

My question is:

Is there a chance of any molecule $A$ make a path through the spaces between the molecules of $R$ without breaking it?

If so, for what $A$ (GAS) and $R$ (SOLID) is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an actual material, or some idealized impermeable solid? In the real world, things like molecules diffusing into a metal are indeed a thing, particularly if the molecule is small and the gas is under high pressure. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: It's some actual material. It's not like that... I'd like to see if it's possible for a molecule, go through the metal (in your example), without affecting it in anyway!

Comment: This happens through a process called diffusion.  See this question.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39006/why-do-balloons-deflate

Answer (score 0):

It is permeation, [the ability to permeate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeation)

> In physics and engineering, permeation (also called imbuing) is the penetration of a permeate (such as a liquid, gas, or vapor) through a solid. It is directly related to the concentration gradient of the permeate, a material's intrinsic permeability, and the materials' mass diffusivity. Permeation is modeled by equations such as Fick's laws of diffusion, and can be measured using tools such as a minipermeameter.

If you have a specific material you have to search for it specifically. An example is [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/aic.690150117/abstract).

Comment: So cool! Thank you, I'll study more about permeation.